# TypeError: c.push is undefined after angular 6 prod build

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I'm trying to build my Angular 6 application with the following command (I'm using the 6.0.4 Angular version and 6.0.8 Angular CLI version):

```
ng build --prod
```

All works fine but when I'm trying to display my build application I got the following errors in my web console:

> TypeError: c.push is undefined (runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js:1:964)
>
> TypeError: (intermediate value).push is not a function (polyfills.2903ad11212d7d797800.js:1:2)
>
> TypeError: (intermediate value).push is not a function (main.3a04e0ee25d4464aa7c8.js:1:2)

Don't understand why my app works fine with `ng serve` but not with the prod build

Comment: I've had a similar issue but it's `(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function` when using the `--prod` option.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an angular or angular/cli error. This error caused by using another script/application that was built using webpack version less than 4